# CultureInfo is not changed although region settings have been changed?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am attempting to change a DateTime that is in Eastern Standard Time to a different date format based on the systems CultureInfo. I am running windows 10. To test this I have changed my Region and Regional Format to France(see image below).I also changed the Date & Time to Casablanca because France was not in my dropdown but it shares the same time zone as france.

However as I am debugging in VS 2022 whenever I call CultureInfo in the immediate window to check the systems CultureInfo, it still displays that the CurrentCulture is "English United States". I believe this to be the reason why when I call TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc() it does not convert the DateTime to the correct region format. Thoughts?

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName);
var convertTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()), timeZoneInfo).ToString();
```

Region:
[image: Region]

Date & Time

[image: Date & Time]

Immediate Window

[image: Immediate Window]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata?view=net-8.0